# Stop unloading a component until user selects Save or Close from a dialog

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component with some form inputs. If I'm moving to another component after modifying something in the current component, then it should wait till the user click on OK or Save from the opened Dialog window.

I'm able to trigger the dialog from `ngOnDestroy` function, but by that time, the next component is already loaded.

Is there any workaround for doing this?

I have already tried, `canDeactivate` but that is not working in my case.

I'm using Angular 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try canDeactivate again, it's the only clean way. Open the dialog there, return a promise which you resolve(false) if navigation needs to be prevented.

Or if you use mat-dialog you can simply return dialogRef.afterClose() which returns an observable of the dialog's result.

If you need to make an api call in the component when user clicks save, you can also switchMap the afterClose observable to that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I will try one more time using canDeactivate, I gave up doing that because, it was giving some errors when I was adding it within child routes.. let me figure out once again..